# Chrome correct autocomplete various forms in the same domain

Tags: html, google-chrome

How can I force chrome to remember correct user and passwords?

I have various login forms in the same domain, in diffrent urls. But chrome always remember the same user/password and ask me if I whould overwrite them.

I tried to make with diffrent tricks: diffrent input names, diffrent autocomplete values in  the inputs. Nothing works. What is the correct way?

Comment: I am pretty sure even Google Developers have no clue how to do it. They don't even have a proper documentation. So there is no "correct way", but there could be tricks or hacks.